# Sample size effectiveness

Tags: sampling, minitab

I work in manufacturing and must report to my boss how effective our sampling is.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

This is an attribute specification of porosity in a casted part.  The data is recorded as a boolean, "is the amount of porosity acceptable: yes or no."  The sample is 4 consecutive parts every 120 parts.  A sample group with 1 NO and 3 YES is treated as acceptable.  Anything higher results in stopping production.

Our porosity target is 30% or less.  The question is, how effective is the sampling in detecting a porosity rate of 30% or more in the population?  Or what is the probability of 2 of 4 samples being NG when the population is at 30%?

I have Minitab if that helps.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: If your goal is 10%, how can one out of four parts (25%) be acceptable?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected to 30%.

Comment: How variable are the porosity measurements among samples at times when the process is well controlled? Without information on variability you can't say much about the information in a certain number of measurements. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.